# How to Hide Sort buttons from Excel Header in VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto

I have a vsto application written in C#, It generates an excel sheet. I have been trying to find a way to hide the sort buttons in the table header (select arrow key on column and Sort A to Z Zto A), right now I am able to disable the functionality but would like to make the button invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the [AutoFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofilter%28VS.80%29.aspx) method on the table range with no arguments.

```
range.AutoFilter();
```

That should turn off the filter.

Comment: not trying to turn off filter trying to hide the sort button from column header dropdown from an excel sheet table in c#